# Swift 4 - UICollectionView Footer conditions

Tags: ios, swift

First off I have a UserDefault to determine if the user is login or not, I also have a UICollectionView. If the user is login, I want to show my custom Footer, if the user is not login, I want it to say No Available. How would I accomplish this? This is what I got so far (the commented out code is what I got so far)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    if (kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter) {
        if (UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLogon") == true) {
            let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "ReviewsFooter", for: indexPath) as! ReviewFooterCell

            let borderColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 204.0/255.0, green: 204.0/255.0, blue: 204.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

            footerView.text.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor;
            footerView.text.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            footerView.text.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
            footerView.reviewFooterDelegate = self

            pickerView.delegate = self
            pickerView.dataSource = self

            let toolBar = UIToolbar()
            toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
            toolBar.isTranslucent = true
            toolBar.sizeToFit()

            let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ProfessionalReviews.doneButtonPressed))
            doneButton.tintColor = UIColor(red: 30.0 / 255.0, green: 53.0 / 255.0, blue: 94.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)

            let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

            let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ProfessionalReviews.cancelButtonPressed))
            cancelButton.tintColor = UIColor(red: 30.0 / 255.0, green: 53.0 / 255.0, blue: 94.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)

            toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
            toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            footerView.problem.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
            footerView.problem.inputView = pickerView
            footerView.rating.rating = 0.0

            problem = footerView.problem

            return footerView
        } else {
            /*let message: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: reviewsCollection.bounds.size.width, height: reviewsCollection.bounds.size.height))
            message.text = "Not Available"
            message.textColor = UIColor.black
            message.textAlignment = .center
            self.reviewsCollection.backgroundView = message*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to return a view in the else clause, so you could create a view add the label and return it, or maybe you return the label itself

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing something like this in my else:

```
let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "ReviewsFooter", for: indexPath) as! ReviewFooterCell

                footerView.problem.isHidden = true
                footerView.rating.isHidden = true
                footerView.submitButton.isHidden = true
                footerView.text.isHidden = true

                //let message: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: footerView.bounds.width, height: footerView.bounds.height))

                let message: UITextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: footerView.bounds.width, height: footerView.bounds.height - 50))

                let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Log in to write a review.")

                attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "login", range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 7))

                let linkAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
                    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(displayP3Red: 6.0 / 255.0, green: 182.0 / 255.0, blue: 216.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
                ]

                message.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes

                message.attributedText = attributedString

                message.textAlignment = .center

                message.delegate = self

                footerView.addSubview(message)

                return footerView
```

It works.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create two different UICollectionReusableView footers, one per each case or change the content inside your footer depending on your application state. If you choose first option, don't forget to reload UICollectionView to trigger  UICollectionViewDataSource methods.